# Yii2 - Adding custom messages to log file

Tags: logging, yii2

Having been trying this all morning, and am a bit confused.
I'm trying to get logs of console commands. Right now in my configuration I have

```
    'log' => [
        'targets' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\DbTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
            ],
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'logFile' => '@runtime/logs/profile.log',
                'logVars' => [],
                'levels' => ['profile'],
                'categories' => ['yii\db\Command::query'],
                'prefix' => function($message) {
                }
            ]
        ],
    ],
```

`profile.log` is produced now, there is no a problem in this. 
My problem now is that I'm trying to add custom messages to the produced log file `profile.log` using `dbProfiling`; for example number of queries or time elapsed. 
I can dump the messages if I used `dbProfiling` inside my code, but is there a way to add this easily to `profile.log` through the configuration?

Comment: Should'nt the level be one of `'info'`, `'trace'`, `'error'` or `'warning'` rather than `profile` which should be specified in the `categories`? so you can add them like `Yii::info('My message','profile')` or `Yii::error('My message','profile')`

Comment: Just added profile as you suggested in categories, and trying now

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam `profile` is a legal severity level in Yii2

Comment: @SiZE yeah you are right as well. But I mean I found that its true that I had to have the level to be info to be able to put messages in the file

Comment: @SIZE yes but that requires the messages logged by `Yii::beginProfile()` and `Yii::endProfile()`, which didnt looked the case here,

Comment: @mrateb so that worked for you or not?

Comment: Well yeah I still have problems, but Im able now to put messages in the log file. This worked by using 'info' in levels, and using the Yii::info() function. You can add this answer I'll accept it